# Serialize model with foreign key Django

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following json:
[image: Json result]
The problem with it is the 'tipo_envase' field, whose id is being returned in my json, but I do not want the id, but the whole object that is linked to tipo_envase, which is basically this json:
[image: tipo_envase json]
I tried to serialize the models this way

```
 class TipoEnvaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tipoenvase
        fields = ('id','nombre')


class PresentationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Presentation
        fields = ('nombre','capacidad','tipo_envase')
```

And the models are these:

```
  class Presentation(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    capacidad = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo_envase = models.ForeignKey('Tipoenvase', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + " " + self.capacidad + " " + self.tipo_envase.nombre

class Tipoenvase(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

In summary the following json structure is required:

```
`{
"nombre":"Frasco"
"capacidad":"410 gr"
"tipo_envase":{
"id":"1"
"nombre":"vidrio"

}


}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the serializers:

```
class PresentationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tipo_envase = TipoEnvaseSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Presentation
        fields = ('nombre','capacidad','tipo_envase')
```

Comment: it worked, just for the record: I tried it minutes ago, but with a different name, so obviously an error occurred, If i am not wrong, it has to be the same name from the model right?

Comment: Well, it has to be the same name as the ForeignKey field.