# Nest model serializers in Django without using rest framework

Tags: django, django-serializer

I would like to know if it's possible to nest serializers without using the rest framework.

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331388/serialize-model-with-foreign-key-django) question and I would like to do something similar but I am not allowed to use the rest framework.

Is it possible to serialize models with foreign keys using a similar approach (nesting) without using the rest framework?

At the moment I am serializing json like this:

```
data = serialize("json", myModelObject, fields=('id', 'foreignKeyField'), cls=DatetimeJSONEncoder)
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
data = serialize("json", myModelObject, fields=('id', 'foreignKeyField.some_value'), cls=DatetimeJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: do you need this json data as an ajax response ?

Comment: Yes, and I know ideally I should be using the rest framework but I am not allowed to

Answer (score 0):

first make sure your view inherit from JSONResponseMixin

```
class JSONResponseMixin(object):
    def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return JsonResponse(self.get_data(context), **response_kwargs)

    def get_data(self, context):
        return context
```

how about this :

1. Broaden your query values to include foreignKeyField.some_value
2. convert the queryset to list
3. return the json list as response for your ajax request
4. access your response as json array in ajax success

1. 

```
    results = MyModel.objects.filte(my_filter).values("field_1",
                                                      "field_2",
                                                      "field_n",
                                     "foreignKeyfield__field_11",
                                     "foreignKeyfield__field_22")
```

2. 

```
results_list = json.dumps(results)
```

3. return JsonResponse(results_list)
4. it depends on your frontend technologie , try to output the reponse and parse with joy

> let me know in the comments section if you need more details